# PowerShell merge variable columns with other variables

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the following PowerShell script:

```
$Top40 = @()
$Top40Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.radioinfo.com.au/knowledge/chart'

$Top40Entries = $Top40Response.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("tr") | Where-Object {$_.className -eq 'layoutTr'}

$Top40 = $Properties = @{
        position = ($Top40Entries.getElementsByTagName("td") | Where-Object {$_.className -eq 'twRank'}).innerText
        artist = ($Top40Entries.getElementsByTagName("td") | Where-Object {$_.className -eq 'artist'}).innerText
        title = ($Top40Entries.getElementsByTagName("td") | Where-Object {$_.className -eq 'title'}).innerText
    }

New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $Properties

$Top40
```

When running this script and then running the **$Top40** at the end, it lists the results I need, however it groups the results all on the same line for each **property** like this http://screencast.com/t/rge78fYwL6V. So, rather than listing the results on the same line for each of the three properties, I want to list the results under one another, like 3 nice columns with the results. I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not breaking the results into its individuals. A loop here somewhere is what should fix this. I am not good with HTML parsing (so there could be other improvements) but from what I have seen the artists are all parsed in order anyway so lets us that feature to our advantage.

```
$Top40 = @()
$Top40Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.radioinfo.com.au/knowledge/chart'

$Top40Entries = ($Top40Response.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("tr") | Where-Object {$_.className -eq 'layoutTr'}).getElementsByTagName("td")

$artists = ($Top40Entries| Where-Object {$_.className -eq 'artist'}).innerText
$titles = ($Top40Entries| Where-Object {$_.className -eq 'title'}).innerText

$Top40 = 0..39 | ForEach-Object{
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        Position = $_ + 1 
        Artist = $artists[$_]
        Title = $titles[$_]
    }
}
```

The code will produce 40 artists and 40 titles. Using a simple counter array `0..39` we build the 40 objects to get the desired output.

Since you are using 3.0 we can just use the cast `[pscustomobject][ordered]` instead of worrying about the New-Object syntax and we just use the pipe to populate the `$top40`. Arrays are 0 based so we account for that by increasing the `Position` by one.

If we were to look at the first 3 hits this is the sample we get now

```
Position Artist                          Title                  
-------- ------                          -----                  
       1 Meghan Trainor Feat John Legend Like I'm Gonna Lose You
       2 The Weeknd                      Can't Feel My Face     
       3 DJ Snake & AlunaGeorge          You Know You Like It
```